# Stop All Audio Cordova Media Plugin?

Tags: cordova, media, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to stop ALL audio playing within Cordova Media? Here is my code inside of an angular controller:

```
function soundCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.playSound = function(file) {
        myMedia.stop();
        var myMedia = new Media(file)
        myMedia.play({
            playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: true
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can keep all `myMedia` objects in an array, when you want to stop all of them just read array and stop them one by one.

```
function soundCtrl($scope) {
    var myMedias = [];
    $scope.playSound = function(file) {
        var myMedia = new Media(file);
        myMedias.push(myMedia);
        myMedia.play({
            playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: true
        })
    }
    $scope.stopAllSounds = function() {
        for(int i=0; i < myMedias.length; i++){
            myMedias[i].stop();
        }
    }
```